# Critical values for Levin & Lin (1992) unit root test with lags

Tags: panel-data, unit-root, lags

I am testing for the presence of unit root in a panel data with $T=12$ and $N=60$. I am using the Levin & Lin ["Unit root tests in Panel data: asymptotic and finite-sample properties"](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/sv/oekonomi/ECON5120/h07/undervisningsmateriale/ucsdUnitRootPanel9223.pdf) (1992) critical values with individual intercepts. I would like to know which critical values to use when I include the lagged dependant variable on the RHS to account for serial correlation.

In section 6, they mention including lags in the regression, saying that when lags are included, the test statistic will have the same asymptotic distribution explained in the previous parts of the paper. **Question:** Does that mean that I have to use the same critical values (on p. 49 of the paper) as the test without lags?